# mySQL create view returns no rows, but create table works

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't figure out the issue here and have done some testing, but I'm new to mySQL queries. Here's the issue. If I run this:

```
create view services_view as
SELECT `innovation_name`,`link`,`category`,`brief_description` FROM `innovation_db` 
WHERE `category`= "Service"
```

I get a new view with all the correct columns, but the rows are empty. If I just run the query without the create view, it returns the data correctly. If I do this instead:

```
create table services_view
SELECT `innovation_name`,`link`,`category`,`brief_description` FROM `innovation_db` 
WHERE `category`= "Service"
```

I get a new table with the correct columns AND the rows filled with all the correct data. Why won't the create view work if clearly the create table does?

Thanks

Comment: You view creation statement is fine.  The issue is probably where you are selecting from the view.

Comment: Just to make sure, use single quotes for your strings as in `'Service'`

Comment: @GordonLinoff Afraid I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this or where to begin.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Good thought, but that didn't work.

Comment: What do you get if you run an explain plan on the select from the services_view?

Comment: If I run this (not sure this is right though) `EXPLAIN SELECT  `innovation_name` ,  `link` ,  `category` ,  `brief_description` 
FROM  `inno_db` 
WHERE  `category` =  "Service"` I get back this: id=1, select_type=simple, type=ALL, possible_keys=NULL, key=NULL, key_len=NULL, rows=308, Extra= using where

Comment: Of note, 308 rows is all of my rows. There should only be 176 rows with "service" for a category.